# Get contact information on smartphones/ppc with windows mobile 6.0?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

In a C# application, I want to get a list of the all the contacts of the mobile phone.

I have no idea if there is a class that exists already to do it out-of-the-box. If not, I would like how to access those information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [POOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914277.aspx).